# Lodash chaining - TypeError

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _lodash2.default)(...).keys(...).forEach(...).value is not a function
```

My code for the specified lines looks like following:

```js
_(channels)
  .keys()
  .forEach((key, index) => {
    // do sth.
  }).value();
```

the channels object is coming from firebase and looks like

```json
{
  "flux" : {
    "name" : "flux"
  },
  "react" : {
    "name" : "React"
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my typing?

Comment: It's works using lodash 1.* version, but with version 4.* i'ts not working.

Comment: How does a set have a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[forEach returns a Collection](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) which doesn't contain a value method as its a multi-value entity.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) instead of [_.forEach](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) - Thanks to [HazardouS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225129/3096717) and [Rafael Zeffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224929/lodash-chaining-typeerror#comment58164571_35224929) for the hints.